# Cannot build Dockerfile

Tags: docker, .net-core

Folder structure:

```
        Honda.Domain/
          Honda.Domain.csproj
        Honda.API/
          Honda.API.csproj
        Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 
    WORKDIR /app 
    
    # copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
    COPY ./Honda.Domain/Honda.Domain.csproj ./Honda.Domain/
    COPY ./Honda.API/Honda.API.csproj Honda.API/
    
    RUN dotnet restore Honda.API/Honda.API.csproj
    
    # copy everything else and build app
    COPY . ./
    WORKDIR /app/Honda.API/
    RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o publish/
    
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=build /app/Honda.API/publish  .
    
    ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:5001;http://+:5000 
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Honda.API.dll"]
```

Trying to build using command:

```
docker build -t honda-api:build .
```

> Step 17/19 : COPY --from=build /app/Honda.API/publish  .
>
> > invalid from flag value build: pull access denied for build,
> > repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied:
> > requested access to the resource is denied

Comment: try docker login...seems like the dockerhub creds are not being configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `--from` flag which is supposed to copy something from a previous stage build.

```
Optionally COPY accepts a flag --from=<name> that can be used to set the source location to a previous build stage (created with FROM .. AS <name>) that will be used instead of a build context sent by the user. In case a build stage with a specified name can’t be found an image with the same name is attempted to be used instead.
```

Read here first about multi stage builds:
https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

If this is what you are trying to achieve you should modify your first line to be like:
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 as build`